# clever image augmentation - random zoom out

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, data-augmentation

i'm building a CNN to identify facial keypoints. i want to make the net more robust, so i thought about applying some zoom-out transforms because most pictures have about the same location of keypoints, so the net doesn't learn much.

**my approach:**

i want augmented images to keep the original image size so apply MaxPool2d and then random (not equal) padding until the original size is reached.

**first question**

is it going to work with simple average padding or zero padding? i'm sure it would be even better if i made the padding appear more like a background but is there a simple way to do that?

**second question**

the keypoints are the target vector, they come as a row vector of 30. i'm getting confused with the logic needed to transform them to the smaller space.
generally if an original point was at (x=5,y=7) it transforms to (x=2,y=3)- i'm not sure about it but so far manually checked and it's correct. but what to do if to keypoints are in the same new pixel? i can't feed the network with less target values.

that's it. would be happy to hear your thoughts

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `torchvision.transforms.RandomResizedCrop` as a part of your `Compose` statement. which will give you random zooms AND resize the resulting the images to some standard size. This avoids issues in both your questions.